# Customizing Analog Time Picker

Tags: android, customization, android-custom-view, timepicker, android-timepicker

I am developing an educational app. Along with other lessons, this app would teach kids to read Analog Clock. After the lesson, app would conduct a quiz where it will ask kids to set the time to say 1 passed 37 by moving the hour, minute and second hands in a Analog Clock.

How can I make this Analog Clock?

One way is to use Android Timer Picker but I am not sure to what extent it is customizable.

[image: this Analog Clock]

Answer (score 0):

One idea:
You can put some `TextView` components with `android:onClick` methods, so when the user click in some number like 5, it will pick 25 minutes.

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvNumber5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="number5"
        android:text="@string/number5"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />
```

And in your activity you will have something like this:

```
public void number5(View view) {
        minutes = 25;
}
```

But if someone have some another idea to pick a real custom TimePicker like from android's, do not use this method ^^

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create independent images for each clock hand.

So you can calculate the angle from the position of ACTION_MOVE event (e.getRawX and e.getRawY). The [atan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions) formula is used there.

this is a sample activity where rotation tracking is performed.

```
@EActivity(R.layout.activity_main)
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@ViewById(R.id.linear_hand)
protected LinearLayout linearHand;

@ViewById(R.id.root_layout)
protected RelativeLayout rootLayout;

private int generalMargin;
private int rayon;
private SimplePoint centerPoint;

boolean isMoving = false;


@AfterViews
protected void initAfterViews() {

    initCenterPoint();

    linearHand.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                int[] location = new int[2];
                rootLayout.getLocationOnScreen(location);
                int rootLayoutLocationY = location[1];

                //since getRawY return y position including phone header need to make it from rootLayout
                float rotationAngle = getRotationAngle(new 
SimplePoint(event.getRawX(), event.getRawY()-rootLayoutLocationY), 
centerPoint);
                rotate(linearHand, rotationAngle);
                break;
        }
        return true;
    });

}


private void initCenterPoint() {
    generalMargin = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.general_margin);
    rayon = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.hand_length);
    centerPoint = new SimplePoint(generalMargin + rayon, generalMargin + rayon);
    Log.d("log", "the program works perfectly " + adjustToCenter(new SimplePoint(), centerPoint));

}


/***
 * transform point into mathematical point
 * @param point the point to be translated
 * @param center the center of the circle
 * @return
 */
public static SimplePoint adjustToCenter(SimplePoint point, SimplePoint center) {
    SimplePoint ans = new SimplePoint();
    ans.setX(point.getX() - center.getX());
    ans.setY((point.getY() - center.getY()) * -1);
    return ans;
}

/***
 *
 * @param point the point
 * @param centerPoint the center
 * @return angle of rotation
 */
public static float getRotationAngle(SimplePoint point, SimplePoint centerPoint) {
    SimplePoint realPoint = adjustToCenter(point, centerPoint);
    return (float) Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(realPoint.getY(), realPoint.getX()));
}

public static void rotate(View v, float angle) {
    // make some adjustments for anti clockwise rotation
    v.setRotation((angle-90f) * -1);
}
}
```

Sorry I've used Java8 and [Android Annotation](http://airbox.home/html/redirect.html?randid=358949715?updataredirect=androidannotations.org) for this sample code but it sould be easy to understand.

If you want to check the application, I've uploaded it [here](https://github.com/maheryhaja/SimpleRotationGesture).